# SQL Server replacement for trigger with data transformation

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, replication

We have following setup:

- server SRV_1 has two databases: OLTP database DB_APP and reporting database DB_REP.

  DB_APP has a number of triggers which do some data transformation (denormalization, uses joins to other tables to match denormalized data) and inserts/updates data into DB_REP
- SRV_1 has transactional replication which publish data from DB_REP
- There are few jobs on SRV_1 which regularly modify data in DB_REP basing on data from DB_APP
- DB_REP is not used by any application, it is only a source for replication
- server SRV_2 is a reporting server which subscribes for DB_REP and makes it available to customers.

The problem is that DB_APP has few tables which are often updated and the triggers make really heavy CPU load. One of the most often updated table has about 100 updates per second.

What is the best approach to optimize this setup? So far I was thinking about such:

- try to optimize triggers as much as possible (right now they use if exists check to do insert/update and I can replace it with MERGE)
- create indexed views instead of triggers and replicate views from DB_APP to DB_REP
- remove triggers, remove DB_REP and publish replication directly from DB_APP using replication stored procedures sp_msins_xxx with data transformation implemented. I am not sure if I can have queries to other tables in these procedures. And what to do with jobs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bad design to have a separate DB for replication, especially as the data is being transformed from your transactional DB.

I do however think it's bad to populate the replicated DB using triggers. We used to have a similar kind of setup, and as you're finding the performance suffers as transaction volume grows.

I don't think its the best idea to replicate directly from the transactional DB either - replication (transactional and merge anyway) uses triggers itself, and the transformation options are pretty much limited to row and column filtering. The last thing you want to do is start modifying the replication procs or triggers!

**I highly recommend moving all your update/transformation logic out of the triggers and into stored procs that can be called from a batch update job which is run periodically (e.g. overnight).**

This is what we did with the majority of our triggers, and the performance gains can be huge. Our users do have to put up with the fact that some data is no longer up to the minute, but that wasn't a big problem in our case.

Comment: The problem is the data need to be available almost online because it is not only used by reports but also by operators (people) to monitor live data.

Comment: In that case I think you need to separate your requirements and the data used by each:
* Reporting, which requires transformations to the data, but may not need to be real-time can use the DB_REP data.
* Live monitoring of real-time data direct from DB_APP, without costly triggers or transformations.

This is how I would approach the two requirements.